# Composer не загружает файлы laravel с Git

Tags: laravel, composer

Командная строка выводит failed при попытке загрузки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

У вас gitforwindows не установлен. Скачайте отсюда https://gitforwindows.org/

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/276933)

Comment: @HamSter, эта причина для случаев, когда по ссылке приходится идти за получением ответа. Здесь же ссылка ведёт на официальный сайт программы, упоминаемой в ответе.

Comment: @Arhad, без разницы, это не ответ,  комментарий